# yWorks EdgeSegmentControlEdgeStyle hit test

Tags: wpf, yfiles

I'm using yWorks 2.5 and I use `EdgeSegmentControlEdgeStyle` to draw edge in a form of some DataTemplate content. I set `EdgeSegmentControlEdgeStyle.SegementThickness` to 20. However as far as I understand this style uses internally `PolylineEdgeStyle` and my controls only react to a clicks in the thin central line. How can I make this style to react to all clicks in 20px height rectangular area?

Comment: Just a quick note: If you're evaluating the library, or have purchased a subscription, you're eligible for unlimited support by our development team. Usually it's easier and faster to just send us an e-mail. We're not really monitoring Stack Overflow on a regular basis (simply because there's very little people ask about yFiles here).

Comment: @Joey, thanks a lot, will do next time a have a question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set `EdgeSegmentControlEdgeStyle.PathStyle` to a new instance of `PolylineEdgeStyle` with the proper width:

```
myEdgeStyle.PathStyle = new PolylineEdgeStyle { Pen = new Pen(null, 20) };
```